# Ubuntu 23.04 server - weird blue terminal background color upon fresh installation - cannot change it

Tags: boot, command-line

I was very happy while downloading the last version of Ubuntu Server (23.04) to install in my hardware, let me say, because i love this linux distro, I really appreciate it, but
after installing and booting it the console background turn into blue on final stages of booting process.

I wasted time yesterday trying to change it, but still cannot figure out how to change it...

What I know for sure, is that this command:

```
setterm -background black
```

do not work as it should.

That should turn the background into black, but it treat the black as blue instead

During the boot process the screen is ok, but at the final stage of booting, it turns to blue..

I still can login, use it, but the color is incridible annoying.

Do someone know what to do to have it working? I want to use Ubuntu, because i believe this is the best distro ever;

Thank you for all

colortest[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSGKj.jpg)

Comment: How does it work with the following [ANSI escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (as a one-liner on the command line), `echo -e "\0033[37;40m" hello` ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this command still show the blue background..
I edited the post and included a photo of the screen, showing the colortest

Comment: I have never experienced a blue background with Ubuntu Server; 1. Have you used Ubuntu Server before? 2. Or some other Linux server? 3. What operating system did you use before Ubuntu Server? 4. What was the background color in that case? 5. What computer are you running (brand name and model)? 6. What console are you using (monitor brand name and model)? Can you set the colors of the monitor in some BIOS menu of the computer or monitor?

Comment: I downloaded and reinstalled the last ubuntu server LTS version, now it is working with normal background colors